# oracle ROW_NUMBER()

Tags: oracle, row-number

I would like to write a query to display this kind of results

| column0 | column1 | column2 | column3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | x | 1 | 1 |
| a | y | 1 | 2 |
| a | z | 1 | 3 |
| b | x | 2 | 1 |
| b | y | 2 | 2 |
| c | x | 3 | 1 |
| c | y | 3 | 2 |
| c | z | 3 | 3 |

column2 -> row number of column0

column3 -> row number of partition column0 & column1

I have tried this but not working

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY column0 ORDER BY column0 ) column2,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY column0 , column1  ORDER BY column0 , column1) column3  
FROM DUAL
```

have you got any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DENSE_RANK` for `column2` and `ROW_NUMBER` for `column3`:

```
SELECT
    column0,
    column1,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY column0) AS column3,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY column0 ORDER BY column1) AS column4
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Great! It's working as I expect!! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

With row_number:

```
SQL> with test (col0, col1) as
  2    (select 'a', 'x' from dual union all
  3     select 'a', 'y' from dual union all
  4     select 'a', 'z' from dual union all
  5     select 'b', 'x' from dual union all
  6     select 'b', 'y' from dual
  7    )
  8  select col0, col1,
  9    row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col0) col2,
 10    row_number() over (partition by col0 order by col1) col3
 11  from test
 12  order by col0, col1
 13  /

COL0  COL1         COL2       COL3
----- ------ ---------- ----------
a     x               1          1
a     y               1          2
a     z               1          3
b     x               2          1
b     y               2          2

SQL>
```